# feathers.js V5 How to check if user is loggedin without using authenticate hook

Tags: javascript, feathersjs, feathers-authentication, feathers-hook

How to check if a user is logged in Feathers,it seems only when using the authenticate hook will user be populated in the context params. is there a way to check on a non-restricted path like in the **find** hook below.

```
export const messages = app => {
app.use('messages', new MessageService(getOptions(app)), {
    methods: ['find', 'get'],
    events: []
})
app.service('messages').hooks({
    around: {
        all: []
    },
    before: {
        all: [],
        // here the user is undefined even if request is done by a logged in user
        find: [iff(isProvider('external'), async cxt => console.log(cxt.params.user))],
        // here the user is defined since only logged in users can access it
        get: [ authenticate('jwt'), iff(isProvider('external'), async cxt => console.log(cxt.params.user))],
    },
    after: {all: []},
    error: {all: []}
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered by  [daff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120513/daff), all thanks to him.

quote:-

> The authenticate hook is what populates the logged in user. It uses
> the authentication information from params.authentication to do that.
> You can check if authentication information has been set by looking at
> params.authentication. So a service method call that allows both
> authenticated and unauthenticated access would look like this:

```
find: [iff(context => context.params.authentication, authenticate('jwt'))]
```